# Image is not running after setting a new docker image and then trying to run the project

Tags: python, docker, pytest

I'm new to Docker and I'm trying to encapsulate my pytest python project into docker image, I've written the python code using pytest library in order to run the program.

I've created the 'requirement.txt' file for docker.
This is how my 'dockerfile' looks like right now:

```
FROM python:3.8.3

ADD tests/test_class.py /

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

But when I run the docker as following:
`docker run -it <image_id> py.test -s -v`

It produces the following response:

```
platform linux -- Python 3.8.3, pytest-5.4.3, py-1.8.2, pluggy-0.13.1 -- /usr/local/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
metadata: {'Python': '3.8.3', 'Platform': 'Linux-4.19.76-linuxkit-x86_64-with-glibc2.2.5', 'Packages': {'pytest': '5.4.3', 'py': '1.8.2', 'pluggy': '0.13.1'}, 'Plugins': {'html': '2.1.1', 'metadata': '1.10.0'}}
rootdir: /
plugins: html-2.1.1, metadata-1.10.0
collecting ...
```

and it got stuck on the `collecting ...` without running the test

when I go to the dashboard I notice that my image is not running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a `Dockerfile` in the root directory as below

```
FROM python:3.6

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /app

# copy the requirements file to the working directory 
COPY requirements.txt ./

# then install the requirements before running the app
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# copy the rest of the file
COPY . /app
```

then build the image

```
docker build -t my-pytest . # here . indicates the path to your Dockerfile
```

Once this is done, take the image id:

```
docker images | grep my-pytest
```

then execute the command

```
docker run -it <IMAGE ID> py.test - s -v
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
FROM python:3.6

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install app dependencies
COPY src/requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Bundle app source
COPY src /app

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "python", "server.py" ]
```

Comment: This is how I run my program py.test - s -v from the work directory and it runs... I want to do the same using docker so I guess I don't have to expose any port for this because I'm not starting any sever... Am I correct?

Comment: Yes correct. Manipulate this and give it a shot then we'll see if any error arises further.

Comment: C:\Git\IntSight>docker run -i 461322d7c7e8
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.3, pytest-5.4.3, py-1.8.2, pluggy-0.13.1 -- /usr/local/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
metadata: {'Python': '3.8.3', 'Platform': 'Linux-4.19.76-linuxkit-x86_64-with-glibc2.2.5', 'Packages': {'pytest': '5.4.3', 'py': '1.8.2', 'pluggy': '0.13.1'}, 'Plugins': {'html': '2.1.1', 'metadata': '1.10.0'}}
rootdir: /intSight
plugins: html-2.1.1, metadata-1.10.0
collecting ... collected 6 items / 6 deselected

Why my tests are not running ?

Comment: When I ran it using py.test -s -v .... it ran as expected

Comment: I am using this dockerfile:
FROM python:3.8.3

ADD tests/test_class.py /

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt


# CMD ["py.test", "-s", "-v", "-k", ./test_class.py"]

Comment: This is my dockerfile:
FROM python:3.8.3

ADD tests/test_class.py /

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt


# CMD ["py.test", "-s", "-v", "-k", ./test_class.py"]

and when I am running the following command to run the test like this:
docker run -i <image_id> py.test -s -v -k /tests/test_class.py

The prompt stuck on collecting...

Comment: It something to do with path **/tests/test_class.py**. Try **../tests/test_class.py** or maybe **../../tests/test_class.py** .

Comment: Can you test your code. It's more looking like a code issue. It seems Pytest hanged somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

In the folder with your Python project code, create a Dockerfile similar to this:

```
# Starting from Python 3 base image
FROM python:3

# Set the WORKDIR to /app so all following commands run in /app
WORKDIR /app

# Adding (dev-)requirements files before installing requirements
COPY requirements.txt dev-requirements.txt ./

# Install requirements and dev requirements through pip. Those should include
# nostest, pytest or any other test framework you use
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt -r dev-requirements.txt

# Adding the rest of your project code to the image
COPY . ./
```

Then, run your tests in the container like this:

```
docker run -it <image_id> pytest
```

Comment: here `<container_id>` should be `image id`. Isn't it?